# one way SHA1 hash javascript implementation?

Tags: javascript, sha1

I have a server that is not using SSL, so I'm trying to find a way to secure the data being passed to the server. My first thought was [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/), but it is not exactly what I need. So what I decided is that I could just pre-hash the password and send it to the server for comparison. So my question is, is there a sha1 utility that can be used for password verification purposes with PHP?

Comment: If you hash the password and send that to the server, then I don't need to know the password any more, just the hash - which I can intercept because you're sending that in cleartext!

Comment: To avoid this you should double hash, the second time using a random one time salt that you would also use server side for comparison.

Comment: good advice @leebriggs I already implemented it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the Stanford Crypto library.  It's pretty comprehensive but if you just need a single hashing function you can extract it from the core (it has sha1 and 256).

**[Refer This](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl)**

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using SHA1 to do your hashing anymore, since it's been broken for a while. Try SHA256.

Comment: Well is there a way for JavaScript to do SHA256

Comment: Come on.. that's unacceptably lazy. https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=sha256+javascript

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you're looking for: http://phpjs.org/functions/sha1:512